# Sample Login With Amazon app crashes after installation

Tags: android, aws-sdk, login-with-amazon

There is a sample application from Amazon end called "Sample login with amazon" available in "Step 2: Run the sample app"  [Sample Login With Amazon zip file download link](http://login.amazon.com/android) . It can be used to integrate with any of our android apps which have signing into amazon a necessary task. But, after build and apk generation and running on an android device, the app is crashing. Can any one please try to install that app from that website and help me solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be much better if you attached any debug information (for example, crash log) to your question. It would help you to get a proper answer much faster. Thanks!

Comment: how do i get the crash log? i installed it in an android phone. I didn't run on emulator.

Comment: through adb, for example